# Elastic Search randomly gets new indices

Tags: elasticsearch

In our Elastic Search cluster.. We occasionally get random indices.  For example:
Using KOPF and click "Show Settings":

```
Index name: wwwwos1.html
{
 {
   "index": { "A" : "quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dogA quick brown fox jumps over the laz"
   "creation_date" : "1434611555943",
   "number_of_shards" : "5",
   "number_of_replicas" : "1",
   "version" : { "created" : "1060099" },
   "uuid" : "Aa9NffIpTRu3011su0d5aA"
  } 
}
```

Any ideas, or how to track down who/what is creating this?

Comment: Might need some more information. Where you call the prepareIndex()?

Comment: What do you mean by prepareIndex()?

Comment: Reckon you don't use the Java API. The command to insert new documents in the database. At least in Java, you need to provide Index, Type, (optional) _uid.

Comment: I expanded the 'show settings' from KOPF and copied in the above edit.. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: I'd never heard of KOPF, but it appears to be a simple administrative program. Not really as an API of ES. So I'm afraid I can't deduce how the index names as created.

Comment: Yea, it's a great administrative plugin for elastic: https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: I've been experiencing this same issue since running ES 2.1 on VPSs. My setup is pretty vanilla, separated into client/master/data nodes. It seems to be randomly happening, once every week or two, creating about 80 random indices (the one you listed not included) over a 10-minute period. The only trail of which are the logs, e.g.
`[2016-01-21 09:34:06,545][INFO ][cluster.metadata         ] [prod-loges-master01] [snooov1.html] creating index, cause [api], templates [], shards [5]/[2], mappings []`. What kind of setup do you have?

Comment: Pretty vanilla setup as well.  We think it's a Nessus scan being performed on our cluster.  So far no adverse effects beyond adding new indices... We thought it'd be solved with an upgrade of ES.. from other forums, but no such luck.  We're running 1.7.2.

Comment: Hah, I just came back here to update that it's a Nessus scan that we have running weekly. I can throw that in an answer, or feel free to update it yourself. We're looking to have our security people just stop Nessus from hitting port 9200 with random POSTs. Upgrading ES wouldn't have any sort of effect. If Nessus is running on machines separate from the ES cluster, and you're unable to control the scans, you could add firewall rules.

Comment: There might be another way: "action.auto_create_index: false"  (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/_creating_an_index.html, and https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-index_.html) for more details.  We're going to try that and see if it fixes it as well.